# Why is assigning to an array show no errors/warnings at all?

Tags: c

> Hello guys! Firstly, in C arrays are not assignable so why is the following command (in line 21) not an error?

```
scanf("%s", lst[i].name);
```

> Moreover making the following two commands shows *error: assignment to expression with array type*

```
struct people michael;
michael.name = "michael";
```

> Theoretically since the first command (the *scanf*) does **not** show any errors it should be safe to assume that the two commands above should not show any errors either. **But this is not the case**. The full program is shown bellow (without the troubling commands above). The two questions I have are:
>
> 1. What exactly is happening behind the scenes when we make the first command (regarding the very baffling *lst[i].name*)?
> 2. What is the difference between the first command and the two troubling ones right above? In my mind the same mistake happens in both occasions (**assigning to an array**).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_LETTERS 50

struct people
{
    char name[MAX_LETTERS];
};

int main()
{
    int number_of_people,i;
    printf("what is the number of people you wanna store?");
    scanf("%d", &number_of_people);

    struct people *lst;
    lst = (struct people *)malloc(number_of_people * sizeof(struct people));

    for(i=0; i<number_of_people; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", lst[i].name); //how can this be a valid assignment?

    }

    for(i=0; i<number_of_people; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", lst[i].name);  
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(lst);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no array assignment in the first one.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I'm really sorry, I meant the scanf command. I have just edited it...!